# Agda's standard library Data.AVL.Sets containing Data.String as values

Tags: agda

I am trying to figure out how to use Agda's standard library implementation of finite sets based on AVL trees in the `Data.AVL.Sets` module.  I was able to do so successfully using `ℕ` as the values with the following code.

```
import Data.AVL.Sets
open import Data.Nat.Properties as ℕ
open import Relation.Binary using (module StrictTotalOrder)
open Data.AVL.Sets (StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder ℕ.strictTotalOrder)

test = singleton 5
```

Now I want to achieve the same thing but with `Data.String` as the values.  There doesn't seem to be a corresponding `Data.String.Properties` module, but `Data.String` exports `strictTotalOrder : StrictTotalOrder _ _ _` which I thought looked appropriate.

However, just strictly replacing the modules according to this assumption fails.

```
import Data.AVL.Sets
open import Data.String as String
open import Relation.Binary using (module StrictTotalOrder)
open Data.AVL.Sets (StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder String.strictTotalOrder)
```

Produces the error

```
.Relation.Binary.List.Pointwise.Rel 
  (StrictTotalOrder._≈_ .Data.Char.strictTotalOrder) (toList x) (toList x₁)
!= x .Relation.Binary.Core.Dummy.≡ x₁ of type Set

when checking that the expression
StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder String.strictTotalOrder
has type
Relation.Binary.IsStrictTotalOrder .Relation.Binary.Core.Dummy._≡_
__<__3
```

which I find difficult to unpack in detail since I have no idea what the `Core.Dummy` stuff is.  It seems that there is some problem with the pointwise definition of the total order for Strings, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Note that the standard library's Data.AVL has been updated to accept strict total orders not based on propositional equality.

These days it is as simple as:

`open import Data.String.Properties;
open import Data.AVL.Sets strictTotalOrder
`

(I would have posted this update as an answer, unfortunately moderator jerks SO is so famous for have decided to delete my post).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at `Data.AVL.Sets`, you can see that it is parameterised by a strict total order associated to the equivalence relation `_≡_` (defined in `Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality`):

```
module Data.AVL.Sets
  {k ℓ} {Key : Set k} {_<_ : Rel Key ℓ}
  (isStrictTotalOrder : IsStrictTotalOrder _≡_ _<_)
  where
```

Now we can have a look at how the strict total order on `String`s is defined. We first convert the `String`s to `List Char`s and then compare them based on the strict lexicographic ordering for lists:

```
strictTotalOrder =
  On.strictTotalOrder
    (StrictLex.<-strictTotalOrder Char.strictTotalOrder)
    toList
```

If we dig into the code for `StrictLex.<-strictTotalOrder`, we can see that the equivalence relation associated to our `List` of `Char`s is built using the pointwise lifting `Pointwise.isEquivalence` of whatever the equivalence relation for `Char`s is.

But `Pointwise.isEquivalence` is defined in term of this datatype:

```
data Rel {a b ℓ} {A : Set a} {B : Set b}
         (_∼_ : REL A B ℓ) : List A → List B → Set (a ⊔ b ⊔ ℓ) where
  []  : Rel _∼_ [] []
  _∷_ : ∀ {x xs y ys} (x∼y : x ∼ y) (xs∼ys : Rel _∼_ xs ys) →
        Rel _∼_ (x ∷ xs) (y ∷ ys)
```

So when Agda expects a strict total order associated to `_≡_`, we instead provided it with a strict total order associated to `Rel _ on toList` which has no chance of unifying.

How do we move on from here? Well, you could define your own strict total order on strings. Alternatively, you can try to turn the current one into one where `_≡_` is the equivalence used. This is what I am going to do in the rest of this post.

So, I want to reuse an `IsStrictTotalOrder R O` with a different equivalence relation `R′`. The trick is to notice that if can transport values from `R a b` to `R′ a b` then, I should be fine! So I introduce a notion of `RawIso A B` which states that we can always transport values from `A` to `B` and vice-versa:

```
record RawIso {ℓ : Level} (A B : Set ℓ) : Set ℓ where
  field
    push : A → B
    pull : B → A
open RawIso public
```

Then we can prove that `RawIso`s preserve a lot of properties:

```
RawIso-IsEquivalence :
  {ℓ ℓ′ : Level} {A : Set ℓ} {R R′ : Rel A ℓ′} →
  (iso : {a b : A} → RawIso (R a b) (R′ a b)) →
  IsEquivalence R → IsEquivalence R′
RawIso-IsEquivalence = ...

RawIso-Trichotomous :
  {ℓ ℓ′ ℓ′′ : Level} {A : Set ℓ} {R R′ : Rel A ℓ′} {O : Rel A ℓ′′} →
  (iso : {a b : A} → RawIso (R a b) (R′ a b)) →
  Trichotomous R O → Trichotomous R′ O
RawIso-Trichotomous = ...

RawIso-Respects₂ :
  {ℓ ℓ′ ℓ′′ : Level} {A : Set ℓ} {R R′ : Rel A ℓ′} {O : Rel A ℓ′′} →
  (iso : {a b : A} → RawIso (R a b) (R′ a b)) →
  O Respects₂ R → O Respects₂ R′
RawIso-Respects₂ = ...
```

All these lemmas can be combined to prove that given a strict total order, we can build a new one via a `RawIso`:

```
RawIso-IsStrictTotalOrder :
  {ℓ ℓ′ ℓ′′ : Level} {A : Set ℓ} {R R′ : Rel A ℓ′} {O : Rel A ℓ′′} →
  (iso : {a b : A} → RawIso (R a b) (R′ a b)) →
  IsStrictTotalOrder R O → IsStrictTotalOrder R′ O    
RawIso-IsStrictTotalOrder = ...
```

Now that we know we can transport strict total orders along these `RawIso`s, we simply need to prove that the equivalence relation used by the strict total order defined in `Data.String` is in `RawIso` with propositional equality. It's (almost) simply a matter of unfolding the definitions. The only problem is that equality on characters is defined by first converting them to natural numbers and then using propositional equality. But the [`toNat` function](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Char.Base.html#791) used has no stated property (compare e.g. to [`toList` and `fromList`](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.String.Base.html#1260) which are stated to be inverses)! I threw in this hack and I *think* it should be fine but if someone has a better solution, I'd love to know it!

```
toNat-injective : {c d : Char} → toNat c ≡ toNat d → c ≡ d
toNat-injective {c} pr with toNat c
toNat-injective refl | ._ = trustMe -- probably unsafe
  where open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.TrustMe
```

Anyway, now that you have this you can unfold the definitions and prove:

```
rawIso : {a b : String} →
         RawIso ((Ptwise.Rel (_≡_ on toNat) on toList) a b) (a ≡ b)
rawIso {a} {b} = record { push = `push ; pull = `pull } where

  `push : {a b : String} → (Ptwise.Rel (_≡_ on toNat) on toList) a b → a ≡ b
  `push {a} {b} pr =
    begin
      a                   ≡⟨ sym (fromList∘toList a) ⟩
      fromList (toList a) ≡⟨ cong fromList (aux pr) ⟩
      fromList (toList b) ≡⟨ fromList∘toList b ⟩
      b
    ∎ where

     aux : {xs ys : List Char} → Ptwise.Rel (_≡_ on toNat) xs ys → xs ≡ ys
     aux = Ptwise.rec (λ {xs} {ys} _ → xs ≡ ys)
           (cong₂ _∷_ ∘ toNat-injective) refl

  `pull : {a b : String} → a ≡ b → (Ptwise.Rel (_≡_ on toNat) on toList) a b
  `pull refl = Ptwise.refl refl
```

Which allows you to

```
stringSTO : IsStrictTotalOrder _ _
stringSTO = StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder String.strictTotalOrder

open Data.AVL.Sets (RawIso-IsStrictTotalOrder rawIso stringSTO)
```

Phew!

**I have uploaded a [raw gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/358ba798323868a7c4e0)** so that you can easily access the code, see the imports, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the really helpful and thorough response! I have a much better understanding of the issue now and am able to progress.  I'm a little bit uneasy using `trustMe` for proving `toNat` is injective since I don't know how it's implemented, but that seems like a completely separate issue.

Comment: `toNat` is a wrapper around the primitive `primCharToNat` which, in the typechecker, is interpreted as [`fromIntegral . fromEnum :: Char -> Nat`](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/625e4152e12d7cde1324c815cf219a870e260977/src/full/Agda/TypeChecking/Primitive.hs#L694). Given the description of [`fromEnum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum), I do believe it's injective.

Comment: I just had a look at Ulf Norell's agda-prelude and it looks like he has [a safer version](https://github.com/UlfNorell/agda-prelude/blob/master/src%2FPrelude%2FChar.agda#L33) of an essentially similar function except that it's strict in the argument `toNat c ≡ toNat d` which is good! I was trying to implement something similar before posting but kept failing. I'll edit.

Comment: Interesting that I ended up creating the same machinery for http://stackoverflow.com/a/35987334/477476

Comment: @Cactus Hmmm. It might be worth adding these notions and proofs about the pointwise liftings to the standard library.

Comment: @Cactus I have just noticed `Function.Equivalence`. I think we can replicate all of this work using that instead. No need to include `RawIso`.

Comment: A couple of interesting things to note since this answer was made: (1) Agda has included a (primitive) proof that `toList` is injective in `Agda.Builtin.String.Properties`. (2) The AVL modules in the standard library have changed to not require propositional equality, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889215/3975928

Comment: @Zambonifofex I did mention it in a comment on the question rather than my answer (I tried to post a full separate answer but overzealous moderators decided to delete it because sticking to a strict set of rules is more important than an up to date answer, it seems).