# Map with Strings as Keys in Agda?

Tags: types, module, functional-programming, agda, dependent-type

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to properly make a Map with String keys in Agda. I've got the following:

```
import Data.AVL.IndexedMap

Var = String

data Type where -- ...

alwaysType : Var -> Set
alwaysType _ = Type

open Data.AVL.IndexedMap alwaysType (StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder Data.String.strictTotalOrder)
```

This gives the error:

```
String != Σ String _Key_90 of type Set
when checking that the expression
StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder strictTotalOrder has type
Relation.Binary.IsStrictTotalOrder .Agda.Builtin.Equality._≡_
__<__91
```

What is the proper way to open the Map module?

Comment: I'm fine if you correct the code in my answer, but changing it the question seems like it would be likely to change the error I'm getting

Comment: No, the error remains the same, since it's because your key type `String` is not of the right kind `Index -> Set`.

Comment: Other relevant answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36271248/477476, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35987334/477476

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Agda's standard library Data.AVL.Sets containing Data.String as values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269333/agdas-standard-library-data-avl-sets-containing-data-string-as-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Data.AVL.IndexedMap` module is for (finite) maps where there is a family of types for the keys and the values, and the value associated with a given key shares the index with the value.

This is not what you want here, since you want all your keys to be `String`s. So just use `Data.AVL` (i.e. the version with non-indexed keys):

```
open import Data.String using (String)
open import Function using (const)

Key = String

postulate
  Value : Set

open import Relation.Binary using (StrictTotalOrder)
open import Data.AVL (const Value) (StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder Data.String.strictTotalOrder)
```

Unfortunately, this still doesn't typecheck:

```
.Relation.Binary.List.Pointwise.Rel
(StrictTotalOrder._≈_ .Data.Char.strictTotalOrder)
(Data.String.toList x) (Data.String.toList x₁)
!= x .Agda.Builtin.Equality.≡ x₁ of type Set
when checking that the expression
StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder Data.String.strictTotalOrder
has type IsStrictTotalOrder .Agda.Builtin.Equality._≡_ __<__10
```

That's because `Data.String.strictTotalOrder` uses pointwise equality (over the list of `ℕ` values of the `Char`s that make up the `String`), and `Data.AVL` requires propositional equality. So the exact same example would work with, e.g., `ℕ` keys:

```
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ)
open import Function using (const)

Key = ℕ

postulate
  Value : Set

import Data.Nat.Properties
open import Relation.Binary using (StrictTotalOrder)

open import Data.AVL (const Value) (StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder Data.Nat.Properties.strictTotalOrder)
```

So the next step needs to be to transform `StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder Data.String.strictTotalOrder` into something of type `IsStrictTotalOrder (_≡_ {A = String}) _`. I'll leave that to someone else for now, but I'm happy to look into it later, when I have the time, if you can't get it working and noone else picks it up either.

**EDITED TO ADD**: Here's a (possibly horribly over-complicated) way of turning that `StrictTotalOrder` for `String`s from the standard lib into something that uses propositional equality:

```
open import Function using (const; _∘_; _on_)
open import Relation.Binary

open import Data.String
  using (String; toList∘fromList; fromList∘toList)
  renaming (toList to stringToList; fromList to stringFromList)

open import Relation.Binary.List.Pointwise as Pointwise
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as P hiding (trans)
open import Data.Char.Base renaming (toNat to charToNat)

STO : StrictTotalOrder _ _ _
STO = record
  { Carrier = String
  ; _≈_ = _≡_
  ; _<_ = _<_
  ; isStrictTotalOrder = record
    { isEquivalence = P.isEquivalence
    ; trans = λ {x} {y} {z} → trans {x} {y} {z}
    ; compare = compare
    }
  }
  where
    open StrictTotalOrder Data.String.strictTotalOrder 
      renaming (isEquivalence to string-isEquivalence; compare to string-compare)

    -- It feels like this should be defined somewhere in the
    -- standard library, but I can't find it...
    primCharToNat-inj : ∀ {x y} → primCharToNat x ≡ primCharToNat y → x ≡ y
    primCharToNat-inj _ = trustMe
      where
        open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.TrustMe

    open import Data.List
    lem : ∀ {xs ys} → Pointwise.Rel (_≡_ on primCharToNat) xs ys → xs ≡ ys
    lem [] = P.refl
    lem {x ∷ xs} {y ∷ ys} (x∼y ∷ p) with primCharToNat-inj {x} {y} x∼y
    lem {x ∷ xs} {_ ∷ ys} (x∼y ∷ p) | P.refl = cong _ (lem p)

    ≡-from-≈ : {s s′ : String} → s ≈ s′ → s ≡ s′
    ≡-from-≈ {s} {s′} p = begin
         s ≡⟨ sym (fromList∘toList _) ⟩
         stringFromList (stringToList s) ≡⟨ cong stringFromList (lem p) ⟩
         stringFromList (stringToList s′) ≡⟨ fromList∘toList _ ⟩
         s′ ∎
      where
        open P.≡-Reasoning

    ≈-from-≡ : {s s′ : String} → s ≡ s′ → s ≈ s′
    ≈-from-≡ {s} {_} refl = string-refl {s}
      where
        open IsEquivalence string-isEquivalence renaming (refl to string-refl) using ()

    compare : (x y : String) → Tri (x < y) (x ≡ y) _
    compare x y with string-compare x y
    compare x y | tri< a ¬b ¬c = tri< a (¬b ∘ ≈-from-≡) ¬c
    compare x y | tri≈ ¬a b ¬c = tri≈ ¬a (≡-from-≈ b) ¬c
    compare x y | tri> ¬a ¬b c = tri> ¬a (¬b ∘ ≈-from-≡) c
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that the standard library's `Data.AVL` has been updated to accept strict total orders not based on propositional equality.

These days it is as simple as:

```
open import Data.String.Properties
open import Data.AVL strictTotalOrder
```